# Preventing hard starts using varied propellant/ O/F ratio?

Tags: fuel, engine-design, restartable-engine

From what I've heard, hard-starts are a very common, particularly in less refined amateur rocket engines, and the only way to avoid them is to either start the engine on an extremely low flow rate or use a particularly effective igniter, possibly similar to the ones used on the space shuttle, resembling a sort of blow-torch.

My question is: **would it be feasible to lower the O/F ratio so much as to stop the fuels detonating, and is there a limit to how far the O/F ratio can be lowered to where there will be no ignition to speak of?**

Additionally, would this prevent a hard start or simply prolong/lessen its severity?

Comment: "to start the engine on an extremely low flow rate" would be a waste of fuel. For lift off you need more thrust than the weight of the rocket.

Comment: I think he's saying that you then ramp it up.

Comment: The SSME started with a low MR - the "lead hydrogen" is why they had the "sparklers"- so it's certainly possible. More for reason of temperatures than hard start though AFAIK.

Comment: Related: [Why did the Agena leak oxidizer when starting its engine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40650/195)